# Can't get CallPay and CallPaymentDetails from paypalplatform.php to work together

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Using the functions in [paypalplatform.php](https://github.com/iamezell/spotaplace-public/blob/master/php/paypalplatform.php), I have the following code which works fine:

```
$resArray = CallPaymentDetails( ... );
// $resArray = CallPay ( ... );
```

The following also works fine:

```
// $resArray = CallPaymentDetails( ... );
$resArray = CallPay ( ... );
```

But this does *not* work:

```
$resArray = CallPaymentDetails( ... );
$resArray = CallPay ( ... );
```

The error happens on the second line, i.e. `$resArray = CallPay ( ... );` and the error message is:

```
'error(0).message' => string 'The trackingId some_string_here is invalid'
```

I can't see anything wrong with the `trackingId` and I can't seem to work out why `CallPay` works if `CallPaymentDetails` is not used before it.

After some debugging, I can see that the following line from [paypalplatform.php](https://github.com/iamezell/spotaplace-public/blob/master/php/paypalplatform.php) is the line which captures the error message:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

but I can't step through that line to see why it's causing an error.  Anyone know that's going on?

---

**UPDATE - FULL CODE**

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once ("paypalplatform.php");

    $payKey = "existing payKey goes here";
    $transactionId = "";
    $trackingId = "";

    // if( user has already tried paying where the payment failed, get old $payKey and use in CallPaymentDetails() ) = true {
        $resArray = CallPaymentDetails( $payKey, $transactionId, $trackingId );
    // }

    var_dump($resArray);

    unset($resArray);

    $actionType = "PAY";
    $cancelUrl = "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] . "/cancel.php";
    $returnUrl = "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] . "/success.php";
    $currencyCode = "GBP";
    $receiverEmailArray = array( 'company email goes here' );
    $receiverAmountArray = array( '2' );
    $receiverPrimaryArray = array();
    $senderEmail = "";
    $feesPayer = "";
    $ipnNotificationUrl = "";
    $memo = "";
    $pin = "";
    $preapprovalKey = "";
    $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError = "";
    $trackingId = generateTrackingID();
    $receiverInvoiceIdArray = array( $trackingId );

    $resArray = CallPay ( $actionType, $cancelUrl, $returnUrl, $currencyCode, 
        $receiverEmailArray, $receiverAmountArray, $receiverPrimaryArray,
        $receiverInvoiceIdArray, $feesPayer, $ipnNotificationUrl, $memo, 
        $pin, $preapprovalKey, $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError, 
        $senderEmail, $trackingId );

    var_dump($resArray);
?>
```

The $payKey variable right at the top needs to be entered in and $receiverEmailArray also needs to be entered in.

Comment: you need to post the actual error codes and error messages. the errorId 'some_string_here' is not a string of 6 chars. How can this be answered if your only supplying a small amount of code and edited error information?

Comment: @JSON, No error message happens.  The only sign of the error I get is that var_dump I posted, which I discovered while debugging.

Comment: If you didn't edit the error messages, try calling `var_dump($trackingId); die();` directly after `$trackingId = generateTrackingID();`. I'm wondering if your not using a valid tracking id.

Comment: If your receiving a valid ID within the spec that you expect, try writing the tracking IDs to a file using file_put_contents() to see if the resulting IDs are constantly what your expecting after a handful of tries.

Comment: I'm not at my work computer at the moment, so I will try this tomorrow.  However, I agree that it's something to do with the tracking id.  what's confusing is that the code which generate the tracking id works the first time, but not the second time.  i'm guessing unsetting the $resArray isn't clearing everything well enough or something like that?

Comment: `unset()` wouldn't have an effect in this situation unless your running this code in a loop. Otherwise `$resArray` isn't being set until `$resArray = CallPay(...`.

Comment: `$resArray = CallPay` seems to work if `$resArray = CallPaymentDetails` isn't run.  If `$resArray = CallPaymentDetails` is run, then `$resArray = CallPay` doesn't seem to work.  Gives the error shown above.

Comment: I posted a response but I hesitated. Check if it works with some empty arguments just in case, and also check that function's code for a bug with a database with no records

Comment: Can you share responseEnvelope.correlationId please?

Comment: I've updated the entire question, hoping it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within paypalplatform.php

In the hashcall function, $API_Endpoint is declared as global and then $methodname is appended to it. $methodname is the operation that hashcall is instructed to carry out. Because $API_Endpoint is being appended to directly (as it is then global), any subsequent calls to hashcall will use the modified $API_Endpoint.

On the first call to hashcall from CallPaymentDetails $API_Endpoint is: 
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails

On the second call to hashcall from CallPay $API_Endpoint is:
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails/Pay

It is this that is causing the unexpected results.

Edit paypalplatform.php to remove the line stated and modify the line stated:

```
function hash_call($methodName, $nvpStr){
global $API_Endpoint, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature, $API_AppID;
global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;

$API_Endpoint .= "/" . $methodName; //REMOVE THIS LINE

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint); //MODIFY THIS LINE
```

So that the beginning of hashcall is as follows:

```
function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr){
global $API_Endpoint,$API_UserName,$API_Password,$API_Signature,$API_AppID;
global $USE_PROXY,$PROXY_HOST,$PROXY_PORT;

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"$API_Endpoint/$methodName");
```

Comment: I've updated the entire question, hoping it's more understandable now.

Comment: All the code is supplied in the question.  I have also supplied a link to the paypalplatform.php file.

Comment: The trackingId is generated in the paypalplatform.php file.  What I don't understand is why trackingId is valid when CallPay is used on it's own, but trackingId is invalid when CallPaymentDetails is used just before CallPay.

Comment: You're right! Sorry, `trackingId` is generated as follows `trackingId = generateTrackingID();` where the function `generateTrackingID()` is in paypalplatform.php.  **some_string_here** was me being paranoid, the `trackingId` in reality is different each time, I just replaced it with **some_string_here** for privacy purposes when posting the question here, which probably wasn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is the strange part.  `CallPaymentDetails()` isn't the issue.  The issue is `CallPay()`.  `CallPay()` works fine if `CallPaymentDetails()` is not used in the same php file, but if I use `CallPaymentDetails()` which works in the php file, but then `CallPay()` fails...  If I remove `CallPaymentDetails()` from the php file, `CallPay()` starts working again...

Comment: I'd check and get back to you.

Comment: Just checked, and the trackingId is different in both functions.  However!  For some reason the payKey's are the same.  They should be different.  Not sure why the payKey is the same in the returned array $resArray when just before running the second function, I am clearing that array using the line unset($resArray).  Does this mean that paypalplatform.php is remembering all the variables which were set when the first function was run and using the same variables for the second function?  If that's the case, how would I reset paypalplatform.php to get it ready for the second function to run?

Comment: `CallPay()` doesn't have a `$payKey` input but it does output a `$payKey`, but it generates a `$payKey` from within the paypalplatform.php files.  The generated `$payKey` should be different from the one used in `CallPaymentDetails()`, but it remains the same for some reason, even if I set `$payKey = "";` before calling `CallPay()`.  I'll post the full code shortly.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I've not added the full code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because it's missing parameters.

```
  'error(0).parameter(0)' => string 'some_string_here' (length=9)
```

EDIT: There also seems to be something wrong with the function when it's doing the first database call.

Comment: I've updated the entire question, hoping it's more understandable now.